# Reading time from file

Tags: python, datetime, time

I need help in grouping my data by date to find `Sum of Days worked` and `Total Hours worked` for each `ID`. My data is in a txt file. An example of my data is provided below :

```py
ID,Date,Start Time,End Time
1,02/11/2019,08:25,16:24
1,03/11/2019,07:54,16:20
1,04/11/2019,07:46,16:08
1,05/11/2019,08:13,16:10
1,06/11/2019,07:48,15:24
1,08/11/2019,08:27,15:26
1,09/11/2019,08:25,16:02
1,10/11/2019,07:49,15:03
1,11/11/2019,08:18,15:29
1,12/11/2019,07:54,16:21
1,15/11/2019,07:50,16:24
1,16/11/2019,07:48,16:25
1,17/11/2019,08:25,15:28
1,19/11/2019,07:49,16:10
1,21/11/2019,08:11,15:06
1,22/11/2019,07:58,15:29
1,23/11/2019,07:49,15:20
1,24/11/2019,08:28,16:28
1,26/11/2019,08:29,16:14
1,27/11/2019,07:59,15:18
1,28/11/2019,07:53,16:24
1,29/11/2019,07:49,16:25
1,30/11/2019,08:25,15:08
1,31/11/2019,08:10,16:09
2,01/11/2019,07:58,15:22
2,02/11/2019,07:53,16:16
2,03/11/2019,08:13,15:05
2,04/11/2019,07:54,16:04
```

An example of the final output I require is provided below:

```py
ID,Hours Worked,Days Worked
1,168,24
```

I have been trying for a week using lists and dictionaries but have not been able to come up with a solution. Any help using datetime methods is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you use pandas library? If yes look into it.

Comment: Please show what you have tried, describe what problems you have with it and ask a specific question about that code.

Comment: So your end result should be ID, Total Days Worked and Total Hours Worked? Is your file a text file or a csv ? Try to code it and let us know if you face an error. Here's a tip -> [pd.datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you can use the pandas library, here's something you can do

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
df['Duration']=(pd.to_datetime(df['End Time'], format='%H:%M')-pd.to_datetime(df['Start Time'], format='%H:%M')).dt.components['hours']
df.groupby('ID').Duration.agg('sum')
result=df.groupby('ID').agg({'Duration': ['sum'], 'Date': ['count']})
```

Here, we read the file into a pandas dataframe, create a column with timedelta values for the start and end times, then group by the 'ID'  and aggregate the sum over column 'Duration' and the count over column 'Date' as this gives the number of days worked.

The output should look something like this -

```
   Duration  Date
        sum count
ID               
1       174    24
2        29     4
```

Comment: this exactly what i want , but when i try this code it didn't work ! shows a 
(KeyError: 'End Time') i don't know why , i never worked with panda , if any datetime or time method , !

Comment: @PyCoder this code works. Can you paste the entire error as an edit to your original post ?

Comment: @PyCoder KeyErrors usually mean that there was an error fetching a key, which is 'End Time' here (a column name). Is the header row in your csv spelled properly? Note that, it is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure that timestamp in your input for each id does not duplicate or overlap

this solution store id: hout works and should be easy to transfer hour -> day

```
from datetime import datetime

testlist = [
    [1,"02/11/2019","08:25","16:25"],
    [1,"03/11/2019","07:25","16:25"],
    [2,"02/13/2019","08:25","17:25"],
    [2,"03/13/2019","06:25","16:25"]
]

fmt = '%H:%M'
dictx = {}
for time in testlist:
    if time[0] not in dictx:
        dictx[time[0]] = 0
    tstamp1 = datetime.strptime(time[2], fmt)
    tstamp2 = datetime.strptime(time[3], fmt)
    dictx[time[0]] += int(round((tstamp2 - tstamp1).total_seconds()) / 3600)

print(dictx)
```